# MarkLogic - Access for xdmp.save function

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

- I have an informatica script that runs with user infa1
- The informatica script invokes a MarkLogic custom REST API by connecting to 
  MarkLogic server with user marklogic1
- The custom REST API has an xdmp.save() function that attempts to save the
  document on a windows batch server (MarkLogic is installed on
  a different Linux server)

I am trying to understand how privileges needs to be set to be able to successfully write the document on windows batch server. Which user (infa1 or marklogic1) should have write access on the windows batch server? Also, how 
could the xdmp.save function that runs on a Linux server (where MarkLogic is installed) transfer and save data on a different windows batch server (or a Linux server that is different from where MarkLogic is installed)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MarkLogic cluster can not save a document to a separate system using `xdmp.save`.

[xdmp.save](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.save?q=xdmp.save&v=9.0&api=true)

> The output file pathname. The path can be fully qualified or relative. **Relative pathnames are resolved from the directory in which MarkLogic Server is installed**.

The REST call would need to return a document or documents, and the REST client (your Windows host) would be responsible for handling the save.